# Why Vue binding does not work in a sample?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Please have a look at example

http://jsfiddle.net/g77uv054/

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/0.10.5/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="todo">
    <h1>My Test</h1>
    Sample 1 <span v-text="form.title"></span>
    Sample 2 <b><span v-text="'' +form.title"></span></b>
</div>


<script>
var form = new Vue({
    data: {
        title: "My Form"
    }
});

var app = new Vue({
    el: '#todo',
    data: {
        form : form
    }
})
</script>
```

For some reason, binding in "Sample 1" does not show nothing and Sample 2 works fine. Can someone please explain why adding '' to string makes any difference ?

Comment: Why are you using an ancient version of Vue in your example? If you use a modern version your code works.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can use a vue instance inside another vue instance.
Normally you either define form as a component or as a class.
I attached fiddles for the two approaches:

http://jsfiddle.net/DarkFruits/g77uv054/1/

```
<div id="todo">
  <h1>My Test</h1>
  Sample 1<span v-text="form.title"></span><br/>
  Sample 2<span v-text="'' +form.title"></span>
</div>

class form {
  constructor() {
    this.title = 'My Form'
  }
}

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#todo',
  data: {
    form : new form()
  }
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DarkFruits/g77uv054/2/

```
<template id="my-form">
  <span v-text='title'></span>
</template>

<div id="todo">
    <h1>My Test</h1>
    Sample 1<my-form v-bind:title='title'></my-form><br/>
</div>

Vue.component('my-form', {
    template: '#my-form',
    props: ['title']
})

var app = new Vue({
    el: '#todo',
    data: {
        title : 'My Form'
    }
})
```

Edit:
FYI, in the second fiddle I removed vue as an external resource and added it in the javascript settings. This also gives you better error messages in the console.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but if I use class to define form and not use Vue then I can not use computed fields and other Vue features in here.

Is there any other way to decouple ViewModel from template ?

I would like to have separated classes for Templates and ViewModels so I could test ViewModel logic without having to instantiate templates, dom and so on...

Comment: If you want to decouple your form from the app but still use vue features, you could go the component way (second fiddle). I am not aware of any other approach. But I am also quite new to vue, so maybe someone else knows of one. You could also ask on the [vue gitter](https://gitter.im/vuejs/vue)